# Chaining ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#from with joins gives bad SQL, missing joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search

I am using postgres tsearch on a project with Rails 3.0.9. To make a tsearch query, I need to include extra SQL in my "from" clause. For example, say I have this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end
```

I want to do a fulltext search on users and their profiles. I can do this:

```
User.joins(:profile).where(
  "(profiles.vectors @@ tsearch_query) or (users.vectors @@ tsearch_query)"
).from(
  "to_tsquery('MYQUERY') as tsearch_query, users")
```

This produces the following SQL and it works fine:

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM to_tsquery('MYQUERY') as tsearch_query, users INNER JOIN \"profiles\" ON \"profiles\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE ((profiles.vectors @@ tsearch_query) or (users.vectors @@ tsearch_query))"
```

But if I tack on another join I get some bad SQL:

```
User.joins(:profile).where(
  "(profiles.vectors @@ tsearch_query) or (users.vectors @@ tsearch_query)"
).from(
  "to_tsquery('MYQUERY') as tsearch_query, users").joins(:groups)
```

Here's the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "memberships" at character 108
: SELECT "users".* FROM to_tsquery('MYQUERY') as tsearch_query, users INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "memberships"."group_id" WHERE AND ((profiles.vectors @@ tsearch_query) or (users.vectors @@ tsearch_query))
```

There should be three join statements in this query. users-to-profiles, users-to-memberships and memberships-to-groups. Only the last join is included, so we get an error for referencing the memberships table without joining it earlier.

But AR::Relation does know about both joins:

```
irb(main)> _.send(:joins_values)
=> [:profile, :groups]
```

I think the problem is from adding that "from" scope call. If I cut it out, I get both my joins. For example, I can even provide a dummy "from" call and get the same error:

```
User.joins(:profile).from( "users" ).joins(:groups)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "memberships" at character 68
: SELECT "users".* FROM users INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "memberships"."group_id"

irb(main)> _.send(:joins_values)
=> [:profile, :groups]
```

Removing the "from" call, this works fine:

```
User.joins(:profile).joins(:groups)

irb(main)> _.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"profiles\" ON \"profiles\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"memberships\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"memberships\".\"user_id\" INNER JOIN \"groups\" ON \"groups\".\"id\" = \"memberships\".\"group_id\"
```

So I'm not sure how to work around this.

My ultimate goal is to be able to do a tsearch search on User and their profile, while also limiting the results by the groups the user is in.

Comment: Note, this isn't just an issue w/ :has_many_through relations. Code:

`User.joins(:profile).from( "users" ).joins(:memberships)`

sql:

`SELECT \"users\".* FROM users INNER JOIN \"memberships\" ON \"memberships\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\"`

note how the join on :profile is missing

Comment: I hate to ask, but... have you considered Sequel? I'm new to ruby and have not tried it, but insofar as I can tell, Sequel's author is a postgres junkie and I doubt this'll fail using it... Sequel has a different driver per DB. ActiveRecord, by contrast (best I looked at it anyway), seeks to implement full-on cross-DB queries. This is more or less guaranteed to fail at some point or another when you use DB-specific features.

Comment: @Denis, I hadn't heard of Sequel. Unfortunately this is a port from a rails 2.* app, so we're pretty committed to Activerecord. I'll keep it in mind for future projects though.

Comment: Yeah, well my understanding is there's a wrapper that makes sequel "speak" active record, for drop in replacement. Off the top of my head, search for a gem named sequel-rails or sequel-activerecord.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this isn't a great answer, but a decent work around: I can get this to work by passing the actual SQL for the joins to User.joins, rather than using the relation names. Might have to do for now.

In the meantime I suppose I'll put together a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Another not so great solution is to wait for rails 3.1.

Added this test to activerecord's inner_join_association_test.rb:

```
def test_from_clause_clobbers_multiple_joins
  result = Author.joins(:posts).from('authors').joins(:categorizations).where(:categorizations => {:id => 1}, :posts => {:id => 1}).to_a
  assert_equal authors(:david), result.first
end
```

fails on 3.0.9 but passes on 3.1-rc1